# Is the total variation of a vector measure $\mu$ a (classical) measure, even when $\mu$ is not of bounded variation?

Tags: measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $\mu:\mathcal A\to E$ with $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $$\mu\left(\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_n)\tag1$$ for all disjoint $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal A$

> Now, let $$|\mu|(A):=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\left\|\mu(A_i)\right\|_E:n\in\mathbb N\text{ and }A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\mathcal A\text{ are disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i\subseteq A\right\}$$ for $A\in\mathcal A$. I've read in a lecture note that $|\mu|$ is a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, if $|\mu|(\Omega)<\infty$. What goes wrong if $|\mu|(\Omega)=\infty$?

Let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal A$ be disjoint and $A:=\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$. First of all, it's easy to see (and that's even stated in that lecture note) that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}|\mu|(A_n)\le|\mu|(A)\tag2\;.$$ So, the problem must occur in the proof of the other inequality:

- Let $k\in\mathbb N$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal A$ be disjoint with $$\biguplus_{i=1}^kB_i\subseteq A\tag3$$
- Then, $(A_n\cap B_i)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is disjoint with $$\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}(A_n\cap B_i)=B_i\tag4$$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}$ and $A_n\cap B_1,\ldots,A_n\cap B_k$ are disjoint with $$\biguplus_{i=1}^k(A_n\cap B_i)\subseteq A_n\tag5$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$
- Thus, \begin{equation}\begin{split}\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu(B_i)\right\|_E&=\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu\left(\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}(A_n\cap B_i)\right)\right\|_E=\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_n\cap B_i)\right\|_E\\&\le\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|\mu(A_n\cap B_i)\right\|_E\\&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu(A_n\cap B_i)\right\|_E\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}|\mu|(A_n)\end{split}\tag6\end{equation}
- $(6)$ should immediately yield $$|\mu|(A)\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}|\mu|(A_n)\tag7$$

> By $(2)$ and $(7)$ we obtain the $\sigma$-additivity of $|\mu|$. Hence, $|\mu|$ is a measure (clearly, not a finite one, but that wasn't claimed). So, is there anything wrong in my proof?

Comment: Maybe this is silly, but I'm having trouble seeing how a vector measure of unbounded variation can exist at all.  Is there a standard example?

Comment: What does (1) mean exactly? A priori the sum is defined only if $\sum ||\mu(A_i)||<\infty$, right? So the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ is not general. What then can follow for $|\mu|$ ?

Comment: @JeanDuchon: Yes, that's what was worrying me.

Comment: @JeanDuchon $(1)$ is summability in $E$: $(x_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq E$ is called summable iff there is a $x\in E$ with $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists J\subseteq I\text{ with }|J|\in\mathbb N:\forall K\subseteq I\text{ with }|K|\in\mathbb N\text{ and }J\subseteq K:\left\|x-\sum_{k\in K}x_k\right\|_E<\varepsilon\;.$$ If $E$ is complete (which is the case in the question) $\sum_{i\in I}\left\|\mu(A_i)\right\|_E<\infty$ is a sufficient, but not necessary, condition.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I don't know, is it? If not, what's a counterexample? Also, what's an example of a sequence in a Banach space that is summable but not absolutely summable?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm sorry, you're right. Here is a working counterexample: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)=(\mathbb N,2^{\mathbb N})$, $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in c_0$ and $$\mu(I):=\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_ie^i\;\;\;\text{for }I\subseteq\mathbb N\;,$$ where $e^i\in C_0$ is such that $e^i_j=\delta_{ij}$. Then, $$|\mu|(I)=\sum_{i\in I}|\alpha_i|\;\;\;\text{for all }I\subseteq\mathbb N$$ and hence $\mu$ has bounded variation iff $\alpha\in\ell_1$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you.  Now I can think about the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge Also, in any Hilbert space with an orthogonal basis $\{e_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$, an element $u\in H$ is the sum of the summable family  $\{(u,e_\lambda)e_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$, (which of course in general is not absolutely summable).

Answer (score 2):

In fact the total variation of a Banach valued vector measure is always a measure, as you are saying. What can happen is that $\|\mu\|$  has "heavy atoms", that is, measurable, non null sets $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that any measurable $B\subset A$ is either  $\|\mu\|$-null or  $\|\mu\|$-infinite.  The space $\Omega$ itself may result a "heavy atom", so that the image of $\|\mu\|$ as a function is reduced to $\{0,+\infty\}$. Maybe the lecture notes wanted to rule out these somehow pathological situations.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say there is anything wrong. You just end up with $\infty = \infty $. It is valid in the classic measure theory. The thing is that when we write sup in the definition of variation we already assume it exists. There is actually a bit difference between real valued measure and banach valued measure since $\left [ 0, \infty  \right ]$ itself is not banach.